How to prevent API URLs exposed in client-side in Next.js?
I just moved to Next.js because Next.js allowed SSR which helped my website's SEO. And I realized that any fetchings that happened inside /pages/api/ directory would possibly be accessed directly on the client URL as well.
For example, my server port is 5000 and my client port is 3000. I fetch my products' categories in categories.tsx from the client side:
/pages/api/categories.tsx
import axios from "axios";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/api/categories`);
        res.status(200).json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Get categories error', message: (error as any).message });
    }
}

Then clients can also access the JSON data directly through: localhost:3000/api/categories
How can I still retrieve the data without letting my API URLs be exposed publicly on the client side? I have thought of fetching it directly every time I need but in my case when I have thousands of categories to show, fetching every time users navigate seems not optimal for the server.
Thank you.

The rule of thumb is EVERYTHING is exposed on client-side. For web apps and web browsers, trying to lock this down will only be a nightmare for you and introduce inconveniences to the user. Instead, your energy should be directed at the backend: proxy servers, access control, rate limiting, etc... stuff you'd want to implement anyways. Every major web app has handled this.
